# A family of seven!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

So in this puzzle the goal is to come up with an answer that consist of **9** letters. Without giving away anymore info (atleast for now) on how to approach this puzzle I'll let you try make sense of it first.

Good luck!

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The 'family of 7' clued in this puzzle is:

> the family of **7 Tetris shapes** - otherwise known as **tetrominos**!

How? First notice that the bottom-right corner shows:

> a key, giving the initial letter of what each of the other non-blank squares represents. These are (row by row):
>
>  **P**rimes (clued by the *top* cube of this pyramid, where *top* is a synonym for *prime* - though I spent far too long looking at pyramidal numbers!),
>  **R**oman numerals (the Roman empire is mapped),
>  **S**quare numbers,
>  **C**hemical elements with 1-letter symbols,
>  **V**owels (the 5 crossed spaces correspond to the positions of the 5 vowels in the alphabet if counting from 1 to 26),
>  **B**inary numbers,
>  **H**exadecimal numbers (clued by 'base 16'!).

If we shade the spaces in each box which correspond to these categories, we see the following:

> [image]
>
>  These are the Tetris pieces! (Note that the vowel box uses Braille representation.) In other words, these are the 7 unique shapes (excluding reflection) that can be made from an arrangement of 4 squares.

This means the final 9-letter answer is:

> **[TETROMINO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino)** i.e. a shape which can be made from an arrangement of 4 squares.

Comment: Well done :) rot13(Nf sbe gur cevzrf, V whfg gubhtug *ohvyqvat oybpxf* bs ahzoref!)

Comment: @Prim3numbah Ah, that's quite poetic actually! I'll leave in the explanation I finally settled on because I think that's also valid - but I seriously went round the houses with pyramids for a loooong time! Nice puzzle, thanks :)

Comment: I don't understand how the Roman Empire maps to those 4 letters. Mind explaning a bit?

Comment: @iBug Sure - the map is of the Roman Empire. The hash symbol overlaid on it means 'number', so we're looking for *Roman numbers*, which are commonly known as '[Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals)'. The letters in the Roman numeral system are I (1), V (5), X (10), L (50), C (100), D (500) and M (1000). Shade the letters in the box which are in this list (CIDL) but leave those which are not, and voila! :)